# How exactly does Laravel make class alias possible?

Tags: php, laravel

What I mean is, how is it you can access the Validator facade without using the FQN in a controller?

Ie, why does validator::make work, not requiring illuminate\blah\facades\validator::make()

How is this accomplished from a PHP standpoint? FYI, I'm not interested in how to alias a class through Laravel's App class, but rather the mechanics of it. Is it done through a custom autoloading function...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise it's implemented in:

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader.php
```

file, using [class_alias()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) function as @user3158900 mentioned:

```
public function load($alias)
{
    if (isset($this->aliases[$alias]))
    {
        return class_alias($this->aliases[$alias], $alias);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is accomplished through the `class_alias()` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php

Comment: Ooh, did not know about that one. I bet that is it. Man, I was way over thinking that.